# Pass string variable in C# to javascript function for use in alert box

Tags: javascript, c#, variables, global-asax

so what I'm trying to do is pass a simple string variable that contains my error message in C# into my javascript function when I call the function. My function call works fine, but it keeps outputting the wrong thing. This might be important too, I'm calling the Response.Write pieces within my Global.asax.cs file and my javascript file is within my Scripts folder in my MVC project. Based on the research I've found, this is what I currently have after help from the comments:

```
function KickOutUnwantedUsers(aMesssage) {
    console.log("Inside KickOutUnwantedUsers"); //for debugging
    console.log(aMesssage);                     //for debugging

    alert(aMessage);
    window.open('', '_self').close();
}
```

It just continues to output this

```
 <%=errorMessage%>
```

I'm not sure how to fix it, as everything I've found says to pass the variable that way, but I'm wondering if I need to pass it as an actual parameter into the function, and if so, how to do that.

UPDATE: Here is the C# code:

```
 else
            {

                string user = s.Remove(0, 4);

                string errorMessage = "THE FOLLOWING ERRORS MIGHT HAVE OCCURRED: " + user +
                    " has either been disabled or the account does not exist." +
                    " PLEASE CONTACT YOUR ADMINISTRATOR. ";

                Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"Scripts/HelpfulFunctions.js\">");
                Response.Write("</script>");
                Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                Response.Write("KickOutUnwantedUsers('" + errorMessage + "');");
                Response.Write("</script>");

            }
```

**SOLVED**
 @Igor was very helpful in the comments, and I did things as he suggested, which for some reason would not work at first, but then the following day I deletedmy JavaScript file, remade it under the same name and retyped out the javascript code and it worked. Coding is strange sometimes. I must've had a typo or something.

Comment: Where are you declaring your errorMessage variable?

Comment: You can't format the `alert()` like that.

Comment: are you using classic ASP.NET?

Comment: The errorMessage will be put in the javascript variable only once, when page is loading... If you're going to call a server-side function, take a look to ajax.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the (badly documented) [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784638(v=vs.110).aspx) is for:

```
// the second argument "true" causes quotation marks to be inserted as well
var message = <%= HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(errorMessage, true) %>;
```

Answer (score 0):

First. Such line as

```
var message = '<%=errorMessage%>';
```

only makes sense in ASP.NET markup file. In js file it is meaningless, since javascript files are not processed by ASP.NET server-side.

Second. Since you are passing message string as parameter, you need function signature to reflect this:

```
function KickOutUnwantedUsers(aMessage) {
    alert(aMessage);
    window.open('', '_self').close();
}
```

and - note the quotes around the parameter value:

```
Response.Write("KickOutUnwantedUsers('" + errorMessage + "');");
```

Comment: I have changed my method to reflect what you have said, but now it says that aMessage is undefined. How do I fix that?

Comment: @MattRothenberg find the line that calls `KickOutUnwantedUsers` in your browser page using "View Source" and post what you see there

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/HelpfulFunctions.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" >KickOutUnwantedUsers('THE FOLLOWING ERRORS MIGHT HAVE OCCURRED: \n\nMR2703 has either been disabled or the account does not exist.\n\n PLEASE CONTACT YOUR ADMINISTRATOR. ');`

Comment: @MattRothenberg you forgot to add `aMessage` in `KickOutUnwantedUsers(aMessage)`

Comment: I don't understand, aMessage is just a placeholder for my function. The variable in C# is called errorMessage and that's what I'm passing in on the C# side.

Comment: this how the function signature in your js file should look: `function KickOutUnwantedUsers(aMessage) { ... }`

Comment: That is my function signature :

`function KickOutUnwantedUsers(aMesssage) {

    alert(aMessage);
    window.open('', '_self').close();
}`

Comment: I keep getting an error that aMessage is undefined when trying to run my solution.

Comment: you have a call `KickOutUnwantedUsers();` somewhere

Comment: I'm calling it exactly as I stated in the original post. I changed it to this as you suggested: `Response.Write("KickOutUnwantedUsers('" + errorMessage + "');");` and it does what it should, but it doesn't output the message at all

Comment: add `console.log("Inside KickOutUnwantedUsers");` and `console.log(aMessage);` at the beginning of `KickOutUnwantedUsers` javascript function. What do you see in the browser console?

Comment: In the browser console it hits the "Inside KickOutUnwantedUsers" and then it shows the message tied to the C# variable where I had **console.log(aMessage)**.

Comment: "message tied to the C# variable" - so, line `console.log(aMessage);` outputs correct text, but the next line `alert(aMessage);` displays `undefined`?

Comment: After the line Inside KickOutUnwantedUsers, it has my error message, which I'm assuming is the log writing the value I'm passing in, then it has errors/warnings about having the <!DOCTYPE html> line. So I'm wondering if it's because my javascript is occurring outside of the HTML? In which case I don't know how to fix it because this code is in my global.asax.cs file and I can't move it elsewhere

Comment: where do you "keep getting an error that aMessage is undefined"?

Comment: in Visual Studio when I'm trying to run my application.

Comment: do I have to pull every bit of information out of you with a tractor? Is it a compile- or run-time error, does it it come from the browser, server-side code, or just the IDE?

Comment: it is a run-time error. the code compiles, but it's when the website runs that it breaks..

Comment: you have to find the line of javascript that throws this error. "it breaks" - does execution stop? does IDE show the line of code that error happens on?

Comment: execution stops. it gives me a big message box with a javascript error saying that aMessage is undefined and it points to the line of javascript that says 

alert(aMessage);

Comment: and the line `console.log(aMessage);` before this `alert` outputs correct text?

Comment: It does. it outputs the value from the string variable in C#.

Comment: I give up. This cannot be. The same variable cannot be defined and undefined on two subsequent lines of code. You have a typo in your code.

Comment: I will edit my original post to contain the code as I have it now.